# How to hook up a controller file for new scene in story board

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In Xcode if a new project is single view application. Xcode will generate a `controller.m` and `.h` file. In storyboard, I can press `ctrl`, point to code to hook up UI elements and controller code. After creating a new scene. I can not do the same with UI elements within the new scene. How do i hook up UI elements within a new scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, your new scene is a UIView you dragged out. If this is the case, its view controller is still UIViewController, not the subclass you want.

You have two options:

1. Use the same 'controller' class for the new UIView as well as the old one.

   - Do this by clicking on the 'View Controller' of your new UIView in the Document outline bar, and then typing the name of your 'controller' class in the Identity Inspector on the right side of the screen.
2. Create a new UIViewController subclass for the new UIView.

   - Do this by going to File>New>File, clicking Objective-C class under Cocoa Touch, then making sure it is a 'Subclass of' UIView Controller. After that, do the same as in step one, but replace 'controller' with whatever you named your new class.

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the new scene you are creating is a UIViewController.
Now create a new file. Name it whatever you like, just make sure that this file is a subclass of UIViewController.

Now copy the name of this new file, select your storyBoard, select your new scene/ViewController inside that storyBoard.

Now go to topbar-> view-> Utilies-> Show Identity Inspector.

Now on the right side of screen, under the heading "Custom Class", paste the name of the "new file" you copied earlier.

If you followed the steps correctly, you are GOOD TO GO!! :)